# EmberJS route model sends api call each time route is requested

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I've got a route that requires to load set of models via api calls. Its working ok, but whenever I go to another route and then I go back to the route Ember is firing another set of gets. How can I cache the result on first Route load?
The code is available here: https://github.com/knusul/embercv/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/routes/index_route.coffee

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: (param)->
    return Em.RSVP.hash(
      card: @store.find('card', 'singleton')
      experiences: @store.find('experience')
      educations: @store.find('education')
      skills: @store.find('skill')
      languages: @store.find('language')
      hobbies: @store.find('hobby')
    ).then (hash) ->
      return Em.RSVP.hash(hash)

  setupController: (controller, model)->
    if App.currentUser
      @controllerFor('card').set 'model', model.card
      @controllerFor('experiences').set 'model', model.experiences
      @controllerFor('educations').set 'model', model.educations
      @controllerFor('skills').set 'model', model.skills
      @controllerFor('languages').set 'model', model.languages
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're calling #find without any particular id, ie. you're asking for `findAll`. `findAll` will hit your adapter, which is why it always sends an Ajax call.

Looking at the Ember Data [store documentation](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/system/store.js#L261):

> The `find` method will always return a **promise** that will be resolved
>   with the record. If the record was already in the store, the promise will
>   be resolved immediately. Otherwise, the store will ask the adapter's `find`
>   method to find the necessary data.

So you may want to consider refactoring your code to make a single #find query for a specific record id.

Answer (score 0):

When you perform at least one `find('myModel')` the fetched data is stored in a record cache, and can be accessed using `all('myModel')` without new requests. So you can update your code to following:

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  # the model method is called once, when app start
  model: (param)->
    return Em.RSVP.hash(
      card: @store.find('card', 'singleton')
      experiences: @store.find('experience')
      educations: @store.find('education')
      skills: @store.find('skill')
      languages: @store.find('language')
      hobbies: @store.find('hobby')
    ).then (hash) ->
      return Em.RSVP.hash(hash)

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  # because we already loaded all data in application route
  # just use all to access the record cache without new ajax requests
  model: (param)->
    return Em.RSVP.hash(
      card: @store.all('card', 'singleton')
      experiences: @store.all('experience')
      educations: @store.all('education')
      skills: @store.all('skill')
      languages: @store.all('language')
      hobbies: @store.all('hobby')
    ).then (hash) ->
      return Em.RSVP.hash(hash)

  setupController: (controller, model)->
    if App.currentUser
      @controllerFor('card').set 'model', model.card
      @controllerFor('experiences').set 'model', model.experiences
      @controllerFor('educations').set 'model', model.educations
      @controllerFor('skills').set 'model', model.skills
      @controllerFor('languages').set 'model', model.languages
```